# Dynamic 2d array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program with a dynamic 2d array. I create 5 arrays of pointer an then I want to put a value on a selected array of the 5 and the I need to realloc in order to being able to put another one in the same array, but I get an error and I dont know if this is correct. Can someone please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void putValue(int** array, int* size, int value, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        array[0][size[0] - 1] = value;
        size[0]++;
        array[0] = (int*)realloc(array, size[0] * sizeof(int));
    } else if (n == 2) {
        array[1][size[1] - 1] = value;
        size[1]++;
        array[1] = (int*)realloc(array, size[1] * sizeof(int));
    } else if (n == 3) {
        array[2][size[3] - 1] = value;
        size[2]++;
        array[2] = (int*)realloc(array, size[2] * sizeof(int));
    } else if (n == 4) {
        array[3][size[3] - 1] = value;
        size[3]++;
        array[3] = (int*)realloc(array, size[3] * sizeof(int));
    } else if (n == 5) {
        array[4][size[4] - 1] = value;
        size[4]++;
        array[4] = (int*)realloc(array, size[4] * sizeof(int));
    }
} 

int main(void) {
    int** array;
    int* size;

    size = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        size[i] = 1;
    }

    array = (int**)malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    }

    putValue(array, size, 5, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
    free(size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What* error? Help with what? It isn't very obvious what your question is....

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` and what `1*sizeof(int)` is supposed to be for?

Comment: Error is the following: pointer being freed was not allocated

1*sizeof(int) should allocate memory for 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `realloc` on the wrong array, this

```
array[0] = realloc(array, size[0] * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
array[0] = realloc(array[0], size[0] * sizeof(int));
```

In addition there is no need to cast from `void*` to anything since it's implicit in C, `array = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*))` is enough for example.

In addition you could use the index that you pass to the `putValue` function instead that having different cases, eg:

```
void putValue(int** array, int* size, int value, int n) {
  --n;
  array[n][size[n] - 1] = value;
  size[n]++;
  array[n] = realloc(array[n], size[n] * sizeof(int));
}
```

Finally mind that the semantics of your dynamic array works by having the size one greater than the current amount of elements, this is not precise, you should start with an empty array and add elements to them. Actually you start with a 1 element array and end up with a size of 2 after adding one element.

Comment: "you should start with an empty array and add elements to them. Actually you start with a 1 element array and end up with a size of 2 after adding one element."

This is exactly what I tried to do, but how can I do this? I can use realloc only after I used malloc so how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems

1. Your `putValue` function will not work for `n > 5` and it contradicts the DRY principle, a better way of writing it would be

   ```
   void putValue(int** array, int* size, int value, int n) {
       void *auxiliary;

       --n;

       auxiliary = realloc(array[n], (1 + size[n]) * sizeof(int));
       if (auxiliary == NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
           return;
       }
       array[n]            = auxiliary;        
       array[n][size[n]++] = value;        
   }
   ```
2. The first `malloc` loop for `array` is not needed, `realloc` behaves like `malloc` when it's first argument is `NULL` so `memset` after the check that `malloc(5 * sizeof(int*))` succeeded is sufficient

   ```
   memset(array, 0, 5 * sizeof(*array));
   ```
3. You should check for the result of calling `malloc` or `realloc`. In case of failuer these functions return `NULL`, any subsequent access to the pointer is undefined behavior if the pointer is `NULL`.
4. This loop is wrong because you haven't initialized the arrays

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++) {
           printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   ```

   accessing uninitialized values, also undefined behavior.

Here is your main function fixed

```
int main(void) {
    int** array;
    int* size;

    size = malloc(5 * sizeof(*size));
    if (size == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(size, 0, 5 * sizeof(*size));

    array = malloc(5 * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");

        free(size);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(array, 0, 5 * sizeof(*array));

    /* initialize the arrays */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        putValue(array, size, i, 1 + i);

    /* print the arrays */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
    free(size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Clear
2. I thought I have to use malloc before I can use realloc?
3. Clear
4. So how can I print the array after I put a value to see how it looks?

Comment: Thank you very much, last question, is this now working the way described by Jack in the last sentence, or is it still having the size one greater than the current amount of elements?

Comment: @firana Jack is right, you need to start with `size[i] = 0` for which I updated the code. And fixed the `putValue` function too.